# What is the motivation to study $\Gamma \backslash \mathbb H $, where $\Gamma \subset Sl_2(\mathbb Z)$ is a congruence subgroup?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Let $\mathbb H \subset \mathbb C$ be the upper half plane. On $\mathbb H$ the group $Sl_2(\mathbb Z)$ acts by Möbius transformations
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} . z = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}.$$
I know that the quotient $Sl_2(\mathbb Z) \backslash \mathbb H$ parametrises elliptic curves, because two elements $\tau, \tau' \in \mathbb H$ define the same lattice $\mathbb Z + \tau \mathbb Z$ if and only if they are in the same $Sl_2(\mathbb Z)$-orbit.

After studying the quotient $Sl_2(\mathbb Z) \backslash \mathbb H$, a common theme seems to study quotients $\Gamma \backslash \mathbb H$, where $\Gamma \subset Sl_2(\mathbb Z)$ is a group of finite index. In particular congruence subgroups
$$\Gamma(k) = \{\, A \in Sl_2(\mathbb Z) : A \equiv I_2 \mod k \,\}$$
seem to be of interest.
I'm missing some motivation to do that. Why are the $\Gamma(k)$ interesting groups, and why is the quotient $\Gamma(k) \backslash \mathbb H$ interesting?

Comment: It's to do with functions that satisfy a functional equation relating $f(z)$ to $f(gz)$ only for $g$ in $\Gamma$.

Comment: Also, for instance, is there a group $\Gamma$ for which $\Gamma/\mathbb H$ is smooth? That's an interesting question, isn't it?

Comment: @DryBones Doesn't $\Gamma =Sl_2(\mathbb Z)$ work for that?

Comment: I don't think so; at least, looking at its fundamental domains, I can't see how its quotient could result in something smooth. More probably an orbifold with a cusp.

Comment: @DryBones I thought the $j$-function provided an isomorphism $Sl_2(\mathbb Z) \backslash \mathbb H \to \mathbb C$?

Comment: I'll try to look at it with greater attention later, but if I understood well, the 'hyperbolic geometry' of this quotient has two orbifold points, with angles $\pi/2$ and $2\pi/3$, which are probably related to elliptic curves showing nontrivial automorphisms (corresponding to the square and the regular hexagon?). I believe this doesn't contradict what you said, since there's also a cusp, i.e., a 'hole at infinity' (corresponding to an 'infinitely stretching rectangle'?), so the quotient is indeed a topological disc; but unfortunately I can't promptly tell why so.

Comment: @DryBones: the trick is that we’re taking a quotient of a *Riemann surface*, so we know that the action is still nice enough near the “orbifold points”. The details can be found in standard texts on modular forms, such as the early chapters (2 or 3, I think?) of Diamond and Shurman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the point of view of moduli spaces, considering congruence subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ lets you consider torsion structure on your elliptic curves.

For instance, $\Gamma(N) \backslash \mathbb{H}$ parametrizes triples $(E,P,Q)$, where $E$ is a complex elliptic curve, and $(P,Q)$ is a basis of its $N$-torsion such that $\langle P,\,Q\rangle_E=e^{2i\pi/N}$ (I think; maybe it’s $e^{-2i\pi/N}$ instead), by

$$\tau \longmapsto \left(\frac{\mathbb{C}}{\mathbb{Z}\tau\oplus\mathbb{Z}},\frac{\tau}{N},\frac{1}{N}\right).$$

You could also wonder about orders of torsion points on elliptic curves, which leads to considering the moduli space of pairs $(E,P)$ where $E$ is a complex elliptic curve and $P$ is a point of exact order $N$ – well, this is exactly $\Gamma_1(N) \backslash \mathbb{H}$ (where $\Gamma_1(N)$ is the subgroup of $M \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $M \equiv \begin{pmatrix}1 &\ast\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\pmod{N}$).

---

From a modularity point of view, let $L(E,s)=\sum_{n \geq 1}{a_nn^{-s}}$ be the $L$-series of some elliptic curve. We expect that $\Lambda(E,s)=(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)L(E,s)$ has an entire continuation with $\Lambda(E,s)=\pm \Lambda(E,2-s)$. How could one prove it?

Well, let $f(\tau)=\sum_{n \geq 1}{a_ne^{2i\pi n\tau}}$ for $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$. You can then check that $\Lambda(E,s)=\int_0^{\infty}{t^{s-1}f(it/\sqrt{N})dt}$ (for $Re(s)>>0$).

Our functional equation would then hold if we had $f(it/\sqrt{N})=\pm f(i/(t\sqrt{N}))$. This translates (because $f$ is holomorphic) to $f\mid_2 W_N=\pm f$.

(where $f\mid_k \begin{pmatrix}a &b\\c &d\end{pmatrix}(\tau)=\frac{(ad-bc)^{k/2}}{(c\tau+d)^k}f\left(\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}\right)$ if $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$ and $ad-bc>0$; and $W_N=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\\N&0\end{pmatrix}$).

Now it’s clear that $f \mid_2\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=f$, so that – as $W_N\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}W_N=-N\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ -N &1\end{pmatrix}$, $f\mid_2 \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-N&1\end{pmatrix}=f$.

So $f$ would then stable under a large subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and it is reasonable to assume that this subgroup is all of $\Gamma_1(N)$.

Actually proving it is, of course, immensely more difficult, and required a huge amount of work with many new ideas.

---

From a somewhat different point of view, congruence subgroups are exactly those finite subgroup indices of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ on which modular functions with $q$-expansion contained in a number field have *bounded* denominators.

This was a long-standing problem that was solved recently, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.09040.pdf.

Comment: What is the form $\langle -,- \rangle_E$? Also, did you mean $\frac 1 N$ instead of $\frac 1 M$ as one basis point for $N$-torsion?

Comment: $\langle -,\, -\rangle_E$ is the Weil pairing. I edited the second part, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: For future visitors, the "long-standing problem that was solved recently" mentioned at the end of this answer has a nice Quanta article: https://www.quantamagazine.org/long-sought-math-proof-unlocks-more-mysterious-modular-forms-20230309/